# How to write an fstab line for full access to an NTFS drive?

Tags: permissions, fstab, ntfs

I've written:

```
/dev/sda2 /win ntfs-3g rw,dev,exec,auto,async,users,umask=777,uid=1000,gid=1000,locale=en_US.utf8,  errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

but I still can't access /win as a user (corresponding to uid/gid specified). As root I can access /win and can see that no permissions are set at all (I supposed umask=777 is meant to set all permissions).

Comment: Why dev,exec,async?

Comment: @karthick87 exec because I want to be able to execute, dev and async because  they are included in default and I don't know what's their actual impact is.

Comment: Try this `/dev/sda2 /win7 ntfs-3g defaults,user,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022    0    0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `umask` you define the options that should **not** be set. So `umask=777` is the same as octal permission 000.

For some examples on how to convert between octal permissions and umask, see this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fmask).